# Как правильно работать с файлами excel, с помощью С++?

Tags: c++, excel, xls

Посоветуйте пожалуйста способ создания/редактирования файлов с таблицами excel. Но без использования VS Studio, а с обычным С/С++. Создание cvs файлов не совсем подходит из-за ограниченных возможностей.

Comment: Самое простое на мой взгляд COM&OLE

Comment: praddos, "COM&OLE" это название библиотеки?  где можно посмотреть пример ее использования?

Comment: это [такая][1] технология


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding

Comment: Ещё есть вариант по-хадкору -- распаковать xls (в действительности это просто zip-архив с xml-ками) и работать как с обычным xml. Но этот вариант неправильный.

Comment: @Jofsey, поправка, вы говорите про xlsx. А xls (doc, chm и многие другие форматы) - [COM Structured Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage)

Comment: тут не принципиально xls/xlsx, мне хотелось-бы чтоб я мог сгенерировать файл как отчет универсальный(читаемый excel-eм) . а если вы пишите что xlsx это по сути архив с хмл-ами, тогда как лучше к этому подходить... скачать либу для работы с хмл?

Answer (score 1):

Самый кошерный вариант - библиотека [LibX](http://www.libxl.com/home.html). Но она платная (((

Answer (score 0):

Как альтернатива - ExcelFormat (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library).

Когда-то ею пользовался, вполне удобно (во всяком случае удобнее COM&OLE =))

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70178/discussion-on-answer-by-blackthorn------excel--).